# make main program wait for threads to finish

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix

In the following code I create some number of threads, and each threads sleeps for some seconds.

However my main program doesn't wait for the threads to finish, I was under the assumption that threads would continue to run until they finished by themselves.

Is there someway of making threads continue to run even though the calling thread finishes.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>


int sample(int min,int max){
  int r=rand();
  return (r %max+min );
}



void *worker(void *p){
  long i = (long) p;
  int s = sample(1,10);
  fprintf(stdout,"\tid:%ld  will sleep: %d \n",i,s);
  sleep(s);
  fprintf(stdout,"\tid:%ld  done sleeping \n",i,s);
}

pthread_t thread1;

int main(){
  int nThreads = sample(1,10);

  for(int i=0;i<nThreads;i++){
    fprintf(stderr,"\t-> Creating: %d of %d\n",i,nThreads);
    int iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, worker, (void*) i);
    pthread_detach(thread1);
  }
  //  sleep(10);//work if this is not commented out.
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Edit:

Sorry for not clarifying, is it possible without explicitly keeping track of my current running threads and by using join.

Comment: If this was a graphical UI, yes this would be true because there is a message loop. You have to have a condition to continue running until all threads are finished such as joining.

Answer (score 4):

Each program has a main thread. It is the thread in which your main() function executes. When the execution of that thread finishes, the program finishes along with all its threads. If you want your main thread to wait for other threads, use must use [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) function

Comment: When the execution of the main thread finishes, at least under Linux the program/process doesn't terminate, instead it runs as a zombie until the other threads finish and then the program/process finishes too. To check this, code a thread that just sleeps for N seconds, then from the main thread create the thread and then issue pthread_exit(0) from the main thread and watch the process alive but in zombie state and then after N seconds the thread finishes which triggers the program/process to finish too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep track of the threads. You are not doing that because you are using the same `thread1` variable to every thread you are creating.

You track threads by creating a list (or array) of `pthread_t` types that you pass to the `pthread_create()` function. Then you `pthread_join()` those threads in the list.

edit:

Well, it's really lazy of you to not keep track of running threads. But, you can accomplish what you want by having a global var (protected by a mutex) that gets incremented just before a thread finishes. Then in you main thread you can check if that var gets to the value you want. Say `nThreads` in your sample code.

Comment: If you use the second solution, don't forget that all accesses to the variable have to be synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

You need to join each thread you create:

```
int main()
{
    int                    nThreads = sample(1,10);
    std::vector<pthread_t> threads(nThreads);

    for(i=0; i<nThreads; i++)
    {
            pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, worker, (void*) i)
    }

    /* Wait on the other threads */
    for(i=0; i<nThreads; i++)
    {
            status*   status;
            pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You learned your assumption was wrong.  Main is special.  Exiting main will kill your threads.  So there are two options:

1. Use `pthread_exit` to exit main.  This function will allow you to exit main but keep other threads running.
2. Do something to keep main alive.  This can be anything from a loop (stupid and inefficient) to any blocking call.  `pthread_join` is common since it will block but also give you the return status of the threads, if you are interested, and clean up the dead thread resources.  But for the purposes of keeping main from terminating any blocking call will do e.g. select, read a pipe, block on a semaphore, etc.

Since Martin showed `join()`, here's `pthread_exit()`:

```
int main(){
  int nThreads = sample(1,10);

  for(int i=0;i<nThreads;i++){
    fprintf(stderr,"\t-> Creating: %d of %d\n",i,nThreads);
    int iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, worker, (void*) i);
    pthread_detach(thread1);
  }

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```